# Iterating through/Parsing JSON Object via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, parsing, loops

I'm having a problem with jQuery/Ajax/JSON. I'm using a jQuery ajax post like so...

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "someurl.com",
  data: "cmd="+escape(me.cmd)+"&q="+q+"&"+me.args,
  success: function(objJSON){
    blah blah...
  }
});
```

It's my understanding that this will return a JavaScript JSON object? The text that the ajax post produces is this (I believe this is valid JSON)...

```
{
  "student":{
    "id": 456,
    "full_name": "GOOBER, ANGELA",
    "user_id": "2733245678",
    "stin": "2733212346"
  },
  "student":{
    "id": 123,
    "full_name": "BOB, STEVE",
    "user_id": "abc213",
    "stin": "9040923411"
  }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to parse through the JSON object returned by the jQuery ajax post... basically I want to loop through and make a div out of each student returned like so...

```
$("<div id=\"" + student.id + "\">" + student.full_name + " (" + student.user_id + " - " + student.stin + ")</div>")
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to do it...

Thanks!

Comment: Can JSON have same key (here "student") i one object multiple times? If not then what you are getting is not JSON.

Comment: Ah yes, `ANGELA GOOBER`...  How is little Angie doing these days anyway?  Did she and `BOBBY DOOFUS` ever end up getting married?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your JSON object is incorrect because it has multiple properties with the same name.  You should be returning an array of "student" objects.

```
[
   {
     "id": 456,
     "full_name": "GOOBER ANGELA",
     "user_id": "2733245678",
     "stin": "2733212346"
   },
   {
     "id": 123,
     "full_name": "BOB, STEVE",
     "user_id": "abc213",
     "stin": "9040923411"
   }
]
```

Then you can iterate over it as so:

```
 for (var i = 0, len = objJSON.length; i < len; ++i) {
     var student = objJSON[i];
     $("<div id=\"" + student.id + "\">" + student.full_name + " (" + student.user_id + " - " + student.stin + ")</div>")...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works! However just a question... how come I can't just do a for (student in objJSON){}? I tried it and it wasn't working... well no matter, it works. Thanks again.

Comment: I would have thought that it would work, but I prefer iterating over arrays using the index.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498107/iterating-through-json-object-doesnt-seem-to-work-for-me...

Comment: One question here. I believe each object inside the JSON list is a dictionary. If we do a `some_dictionary.attribute` in normal Python, we get an `AttributeError`. How then is it valid here? Is it a different kind of dictionary, or doesn't behave like a dictionary at all?

Comment: @SidharthSamant this is JavaScript. In JavaScript you can refer to the properties of an object either using `obj['property']` or `obj.property` as long as the name of the property is valid with respect to JavaScript naming guidelines. If it contains illegal characters for a JavaScript name, then you're limited to just the first option.

Comment: @tvanfosson oh right. Forgot. Sorry. Was frustrated with hours of googling for my Python problem, and when I stumbled here, I didn't even see whether this question was tagged with Python. My bad.

Answer (score 4):

The JSON you have currently will not work because the second "student" effectively replaces the first, since these are just properties in an object.

If you can control the JSON output, change it to:

```
{
  "student":[{
    "id": 456,
    "full_name": "GOOBER, ANGELA",
    "user_id": "2733245678",
    "stin": "2733212346"
    },{
    "id": 123,
    "full_name": "BOB, STEVE",
    "user_id": "abc213",
    "stin": "9040923411"
  }]
}
```

Then you have an an array which you can loop over:

```
for(var i=0; i<objJSON.student.length; i++) {
  ...objJSON.student[i]...
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a problem with that JSON - the outer curly braces should be square brackets, as you want a list, not a map (aka object). With all objects in the map having the same key, it won't parse right - the last value will overwrite the previous under most parsers.

You want:

```
[
  {
    "id": 456,
    "full_name": "GOOBER, ANGELA",
    "user_id": "2733245678",
    "stin": "2733212346"
  },
  {
    "id": 123,
    "full_name": "BOB, STEVE",
    "user_id": "abc213",
    "stin": "9040923411"
  }
]
```

or alternatively a map with different keys:

```
{
  "456":{
    "id": 456,
    "full_name": "GOOBER, ANGELA",
    "user_id": "2733245678",
    "stin": "2733212346"
  },
  "123":{
    "id": 123,
    "full_name": "BOB, STEVE",
    "user_id": "abc213",
    "stin": "9040923411"
  }
}
```

You'd be better off using $.getJSON, which is a specialised version of $.ajax for this purpose.

```
$.getJSON("someurl.com", function(students) {
  $.each(students, function() { 
    $("<div id=\"" + student.id + "\">" + student.full_name + " (" + student.user_id + " - " + student.stin + ")</div>").appendTo($container);
  });
});
```

Comment: There's an error in your first suggestion: you still have property names ("student") for entries in your array. Will remove downvote when fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = '[
  {
      "id": 456,
      "full_name": "GOOBER, ANGELA",
      "user_id": "2733245678",
      "stin": "2733212346"
  },
  {
      "id": 123,
      "full_name": "BOB, STEVE",
      "user_id": "abc213",
      "stin": "9040923411"
   }
]';

$.each(data, function(index, val) {
    alert(val.id);
    alert(val.full_name);
    alert(val.user_id);
    alert(val.stin);    
})
```