# how to display json data in div from webservice through jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I have made a getdata webmethod which returns the data

```
    function GetService() {
       debugger;
//        var prod = $('#txt_num1').val();
//        var price = $('#txt_num2').val();
//        var active = $('#txt_num3').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService1.asmx/getdata",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError,
        });

        function OnSuccess(data, status) {
            $("#lblResult").removeClass("loading");
            $("#lblResult").html($.parseJSON(data.d));
        }

        function OnError(request, status, error) {
            $("#lblResult").removeClass("loading");
            $("#lblResult").html(request.statusText);

        }
    }
```

Where am I going wrong? How can i display data from the webservice through
jquery in div?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637334/iterating-through-parsing-json-object-via-javascript

Comment: not need use $.parseJSON(data.d)
because dataType: "json" already parse json,
data is js object, just $("#lblResult").html(data.d);

Comment: but how cani show multiple data ?

Comment: show your json format from server

Comment: iam getting internal server error msg.

Comment: '[WebMethod]
        public DataSet getdata()
        {
            string conn = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress; initial catalog=Test; user id=sa; pwd=manager;";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from PRODUCT", connection);

            DataSet dt = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dt);
            connection.Close();
            return dt;

        }'

Comment: if you get internal server error, then error in script on server

Comment: do i have to convert the dataset to string?

Comment: yeah, you should make encode from array to json string, for example in php json_encode($array)

Comment: and how can i do That  in .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialize your response:

```
            [WebMethod]
            public HttpResponseMessage getdata()
            {
                string conn = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress; initial catalog=Test; user id=sa; pwd=manager;"; 
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn); 
                connection.Open(); 
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from PRODUCT", connection); 
                DataSet dt = new DataSet(); 
                da.Fill(dt); 
                connection.Close();

                var resp = new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dt))
                };
                resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                return resp;
            }
```

JS:

```
function OnSuccess(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }

function OnError(request, status, error) {
            console.trace();
        }

function GetService() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService1.asmx/getdata",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError,
        });
}
```

Comment: and how can i send it in xml ?