# php multidimensional array to js

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I know this question is a duplicate but I really would like some help with this. I know the only way to send a php array to js is by encoding with json. Well I tried that but nothing works. Here's my code:

```
<?php

Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

    $months = Array();

    $months = ['January'=>array(), 'February'=>array(), 'March'=>array(), 'April'=>array(), 'May'=>array(), 'June'=>array(), 'July'=>array(), 'August'=>array(), 'September'=>array(), 
                        'October'=>array(), 'November'=>array(), 'December'=>array() ]; 



    // Connect to MySQL
         if ( !( $database = mysql_connect( "localhost",
            "root", "" ) ) )                      
            die( "Could not connect to database </body></html>" );

    // open Events database
         if ( !mysql_select_db( "Events", $database ) )
            die( "Could not open Events database </body></html>" );

            foreach($months as $month => $arr) {

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posted_events WHERE Month_ = '$month' ") 
                    or die ('Error updating database because: '.mysql_error());

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $months[$month][] =  $row['DayNum']; 

    }
}

            echo "var months = jQuery.parseJSON('$months');";
<?php
```

So the JS array variable 'months' should contain all the elements that was in the PHP's  array variable right? Well it doesn't work. I don't know what's wrong. Help please? I need to use this array in my external JS file to do some more work with my program, so it's really important. Thanks guys.

Comment: you need to `json_encode` `$months`

Comment: Why not just do `echo "var months = " . json_encode($months) . ";";`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to encode the JSON data using PHP. This can be done using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode). Once it's encoded, you can pass the variable to Javascript, like so:

```
$months = json_encode($months);
echo "var months = $months ;";
```

Also, you're currently using `jQuery.parseJSON`. But, the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) says:

> The JSON standard does not permit "control characters" such as a tab or newline. An example like `$.parseJSON('{"testing":"1\t2\n3"}')` will throw an error in most implementations because the JavaScript parser converts the string's tab and newline escapes into literal tab and newline; doubling the backslashes like `1\\t2\\n3` yields expected results. This problem is often seen when injecting JSON into a JavaScript file from a server-side language such as PHP.

Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) instead.

```
json = JSON.parse(months);
for(var i in json) {

//code

}
```

Most browsers support this, but for those that doesn't, you can use [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks that worked! Anything I need to do in my JS file to get to use the elements in the array? Cause I can't seem to get them

Comment: if it's possible, can you can show me the code on how to parse it?

Comment: @Kay: This has been asked and answered many times before. Please take a look at some of them (eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637334/)

Comment: Ok getting some problem here with the JS part. Say for example, I want to alert elements from the array, its not working. Shouldn't this syntax be correct? alert(months[August][1]); Just as an example