# how to browse json content with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

i have a JSON code like this

```
    [{"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/exart.JPG"},{"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/bost.png"},
    {"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/03.png"},
    {"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/04.png"},{"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/05.png"},
    {"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/06.png"},{"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/07.png"},
    {"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/08.png"},{"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/09.png"},
    {"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/10.png"},{"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/11.png"},
    {"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/12.png"},{"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/13.png"},
    {"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/14.png"},{"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/15.png"},
    {"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/16.png"},{"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/17.png"},
    {"url":"http:\/\/mysite.xx\/img\/18.png"}]
```

how i can browse all the lines ? per example when i go to http://mysite.xx/my_post/#1 i have to see the first url in my JSON code  " http://mysite.xx/img/exart.JPG " in a

Comment: sidenote: `#` hashtags cannot be read server side

Comment: i wanted to browse it  with javascript !

Comment: thats why the answer below doesn't really answer this question, i don't know why the others even upvoted the answer, when you click that link with the hashtag `#1`, that wont even reach php, making that json decode senseless, unless make an ajax call, or just plainly use javascript alone

Comment: I think you might need to clarify your question a little bit.  I'm assuming the array above is what ends up on the server side?  If so, why do you want to browse it with javascript?  I know almost nothing about Wordpress but I'm pretty sure it doesn't use Nodejs on the server.  Or are you trying to use javascript to look at the array before it's posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637373/1042903

Also this example from w3schools.com

```
<script>
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.employees[1].firstName + " " + obj.employees[1].lastName;
</script>
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp

If you want, you can google with this keyword, "json parse for loop javascript"

Answer (score 4):

just use

```
$data = json_decode($data);
$url_5 = $data[5]['url']; // the value here is "http://mysite.xx/img/06.png"
```

it will give you array with hashes with 'url' key.
and do whatever you want with it

Comment: $arr = json_decode($json, true);

$data = json_decode($json); thank's 

is it possible to do the same thing with Javascript ?

Comment: JSON.parse(json_test); is what you're looking for.

Comment: as @kolja said, its pretty same in javascript...