# Passing json url to Google Charts while aggregating data? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I have a json url that I want to use for my google charts - specifically I'm making a table if "aggregated results," ie volume of a specific month.

I'm grabbing my json using $.getJson, but I'm having trouble figuring out how I can do calculations on the json other than looping through. Can I make a secondary function in another file to declutter if a for loop is all I can do?

Thanks

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637334/iterating-through-parsing-json-object-via-javascript

Answer (score 0):

once you have created the `DataTable`
there are [Data Manipulation Methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data) you can use to `group` and `aggregate` the data

you can use the standard agg functions...

> `google.visualization.data.avg`
>   `google.visualization.data.count`
>   `google.visualization.data.max`
>   `google.visualization.data.min`
>   `google.visualization.data.sum`

or write your own, the function will receive an array of values from the `column` provided

*column definition:*

`{'column': 3, 'aggregation': doubleSum, 'type': 'number', 'label': 'double minutes'}`

*agg function:*

```
function doubleSum(values) {
  var groupValue = 0;
  values.forEach(function (v) {
    groupValue += (v * 2);
  });
  return groupValue;
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {id: 'dat_ym', label: 'Start Date', type: 'date'},
        {id: 'user-id', label: 'User-Id', type: 'string'},
        {id: 'customer-id', label: 'Customer-Id', type: 'string'},
        {id: 's_minutes', label: 'minutes', type: 'number'}
      ],
      rows: [
        {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 01, 01')}, {v: '44836'}, {v: '67205'}, {v: 1122} ]},
        {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 01, 01')}, {v: '86495'}, {v: '67205'}, {v: 332} ]},
        {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 01, 01')}, {v: '44836'}, {v: '228626'}, {v: 90} ]},
        {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 01, 01')}, {v: '86495'}, {v: '228626'}, {v: 334} ]},
        {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 02, 01')}, {v: '44836'}, {v: '67205'}, {v: 554} ]},
        {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 02, 01')}, {v: '86495'}, {v: '67205'}, {v: 819} ]},
        {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 02, 01')}, {v: '44836'}, {v: '228626'}, {v: 420} ]},
        {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 02, 01')}, {v: '86495'}, {v: '228626'}, {v: 544} ]},
      ]
    });

    // group data by date, customer
    var grouped_data = google.visualization.data.group(
      data,
      [0, 2],
      [
        {'column': 3, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
        {'column': 3, 'aggregation': doubleSum, 'type': 'number', 'label': 'double minutes'}
      ]
    );

    // use custom aggregation
    function doubleSum(values) {
      var groupValue = 0;
      values.forEach(function (v) {
        groupValue += (v * 2);
      });
      return groupValue;
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(grouped_data);
  },
  packages:['table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```